# CKEditor5 reinitializing the toolbar options programmatically without reinitializing the whole editor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor5

Using CKEditor5 I've initialized a toolbar with a certain number of options.
However when a checkbox is selected, I would like to reinitialize just the toolbar with less or more toolbar options, without destroying the CKEditor and reinitializing the whole editor again.

Is there a way this can be done programmatically in javascript/jquery? I see examples for ckeditor4 but have not seen anything for ckeditor5.

Thank you in advance.

Below is how I have my CKEditor5 initialized:

```
<html>
<div class="mb-3 row">
            <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Bulletin Text</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.BulletinText, new { @id = "BulletinText", @style = "display:none;" })
            </div>
        </div>
</html>

<script>
let theEditor;

ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#BulletinText'), {
            ckfinder: {
                uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json'
            },
            removePlugins: ['MediaEmbedToolbar']
            },
            alignment: {
                options: ['left', 'right', 'center', 'justify']
            },
            toolbar: {
                items: [
                    'heading', '|',
                    'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
                    'fontfamily', 'fontsize', 'fontcolor', 'fontbackgroundcolor', 'highlight', '|',
                    'link', '|',
                    'bulletedlist', 'numberedlist', '-', //todolist
                    'outdent', 'indent', 'alignment', '|',
                    'horizontalline', 'blockquote', 'inserttable', '|',
                    //'-', //page break
                    'ckfinder', 'imageupload', '|', //'mediaembed',
                    'sourceediting', '|',
                    'undo', 'redo', "specialCharacters"
                ]
            }
        })
        .then(editor => {
theEditor = editor;
            console.log(editor);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
</script>
```